# How to improve camera shooting responsiveness?

Tags: performance, camera

Is there a camera application (or other solution) that has quick response time between button press and taking the picture?

On HTC Hero, the delay from button press to shutter is painfully long - focusing, etc seem to take a lot of time with the stock camera app.

On HTC EVO with the stock Camera app, distant shots focus and shoot quickly. However, closer shots can take some time focusing.

Comment: Its the same on the droid too.

Comment: I'd be content even with something that works like the "half-press" option on many cameras.  When half-pressed, the camera focuses and sets up for lighthing.  Then when fully pressed, the shot is taken immediately.  An app with two separate buttons, one to take readings then lock the settings, and one to shoot would be fine.

Comment: Whoops, my bad.  I misread you question.  Actually, the Droid does have the half-press focus feature and the time between button press and shutter isn't half bad.  The time between opening the app and when you can actually take a picture is painfully long for me because it has the normal app opening lag, then the shutters does something weird and it automatically tries to focus... I'm impatient.

Comment: On EVO startup time is great.  Button is a software button only, so there's nothing to half-press.

Comment: Oh, that's not cool :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you tap on the screen to set a place for the focus, you'll gain some seconds for the effective shoot.

It's also allow you to focus on a special part of the picture.

I hope it's help.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off other processing features, like face recognition, may also improve performance... though at the expense of other benefits.